# Database connection issue in MVC3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-express

I successfully followed the contoso university tutorial, getting it to work with SQL Express in VS 2010 - creating the DB in the App_Data folder.  The tutorial follows the EF Code First model.  Wanting to see the data in the tables, I opened the database in Server Explorer and was able to view the table data.

Now when I run it again, I can no longer access the database - the error given is:

> One or more files do not match the primary file of the database. If you are attempting to attach a database, retry the operation with the correct files.  If this is an existing database, the file may be corrupted and should be restored from a backup.
>   Cannot open database "SchoolDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'DEV\bwilliams'.
>   Log file  'C:\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\App_Data\SchoolDB.ldf' does not match the primary file.  It may be from a different database or the log may have been rebuilt previously.

DEV\bwilliams would be windows authentication.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="SchoolContext"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|SchoolDB.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried to open the DB again in server explorer and it tells me that the login failed.  So I figured I could drop the database and have EF recreate it - but after doing so, I still receive the same error.  The whole point is to create a project and deploy to an actual server, but I can't seem to get past these connection issues.

Update:  Changing the name of the database in the connection string creates the new database and all is well.  However, opening it up in Server Explorer in VS 2010 causes the same problem.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Shouldn't your connection string also include the username and password to db ?

Comment: According to what I have read, Integrated Security=SSPI should work for windows authentication.  Something I don't understand is going on behind the scenes - and the memberswhip database connection string is set up for you and works fine!  I can't seem to find a solution that works consistently.